# PyDev method creation via Control + 1

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In PyDev I can write:

```
my_function()
```

and I can hit Control + 1 to "Create my_function method". Now, the new function body gets inserted before the my_function() call.

```
def my_function():
    pass

my_function()
```

This is OK for functions but if I do the same in a class `__init__` the new method will be inserted before the `__init__`, which is not desirable. Is there a way to change this? I have already tried Shift + Enter in the context menu popping up, but it did not help.

Comment: Just for completeness, this really is currently not an option in PyDev ( thanks for reporting it at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/267 )

Comment: I think you meant: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/221

Comment: Yeap, sorry, 221 is the proper one :)